# chess24 castling rules

Tags: rules, castling

Can someone explain to me, why on chess24.com white cannot castle in the situation in the picture? King never moved, neither did either of the rooks. When the queen was moved to `d2` castling was not allowed queenside either. When I take the moves from the game and import to lichess, castling is allowed there. What am I missing?[image]

Comment: What happened if you click on the h1 rook? There was a green square on it. The h1 square shouldn't have highlighted if castling was not allowed.

Comment: This seems to be an error (the same occured to me), normally castling works fine at chess24.

Comment: It's a temporary bug. Moving the king onto the rook will castle. This will be fixed soon.

Comment: Anyway, castling is not a great move in this position ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After clicking on the king, the rook is outlined in green, as shown in your both your own image, and mine below. [image: Chess24 with castle option highlighted]

If you click the rook after clicking the king, castling will occur, shown in the image below:
[image: Chess24 after castling]

Comment: I can confirm that castling works like this. You can either click the king and then the rook or you can drag the king onto the rook. I will restrain any comments on such a change but I will move back to lichess, since I can only finish about 50% games against the online engine which tends to disconnect and people comment that this is  due to non premium account. What a shame.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug. Lost 2 games today because I could not castle

Edit They changed the way you castle. You have to click on the rook now.